# ReferenceField assigning

Tags: mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have model:

```
from flask.ext.security import currennt_user
#instance of LocalProxy wrapped model User(db.Document)

class ContactModel(db.Document, SomeMixin):
    user = db.ReferenceField(User, verbose_name='User', required=True)
```

And faced strange behavior of ReferenceField. Why is working following code:

```
model = ContactModel(user = current_user.pk, ....)
```

And does not following:

```
model = ContactModel()
model.user = current_user.pk
```

The same issue when I trying to do:
    model = ContactModel()
    model.user = current_user

Last two pieaces of code throws an error: `ValidationError: ValidationError (ContactModel:None) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents: ['user'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_user.pk` has `ObjectId` type (just id, no info about collection).

`current_user` has [`LocalProxy`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py#L250) type.

You can't save reference as `ObjectId` because there are no information about reference collection and mongo use for this `BDRef`.

You can get `DBRef` object from mongoengine document with `Document.to_dbref` method.

So mognoenginge check type to get `DBRef` explicitly or get it from document with `to_dbref`.

For `current_user` you can call `to_dbref` to get `DBRef` object or `_get_current_object()` to get real `User` object.